# Open part of html page

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview

I want to open part of html page in UIWebView.
I found good code, but I can't find tags, which I need.

I want to open only text (not title) and comments in different UIWebViews from URL (iOS version): http://smartfiction.ru/random?random

What tags I need to use?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Man, What language is that in the page of the link? :-0

Comment: Use a non validating XML parser to extract the content, put it together on a new HTML page, and load it in the UIWebView. This may help: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html Start loading the page to a NSString, then to NSData, and use PerformHTMLXPathQuery.

Comment: What do you mean by text and comment?  Do you want to strip all html tags?

Answer (score 0):

so, texts starts with these tags :

> h3 1 h3 p А на самом деле...

Thy to use them.